# Storing entities with dynamic set of properties in a table (and using fixed columns or key-value tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, key-value

I would like to store people's information in the database (table). Every person can have a different set of properties. I would like to store all these properties. But creating fixed number of columns does not make my application scalable.

So, another approach is to store these values inside key-value tables which leads to tables with a few columns but a huge number of rows.

So I am wondering if there is another way of storing these information which is also easy and fast to query.

Comment: just for completeness sake, check the sparse columns feature of SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Database are you using.

One solution (if your DB supports) could be storing the person's information in an XML Format.

Comment: Right now it's SQL Server and a possibility of MySQL in the future.

Comment: Both of them support XML data. So you could store your information in the form of XML

Comment: Can you query them in the same way as tables? What if a person does not have a certain attribute?

Comment: Yes. You could simply create an object for the person and have all the properties defined for it. When entering it into DB, simply serialize it and store. When retrieving, you could de-serialize them back and get the object to use. Whats your code written in ??

Comment: C#. The thing is, then I need to query that XML table. Are they any slower than normal tables? Your solution sounds very interesting.

Comment: Its the same table with a column of XML type. That would store the complete XML that would represent a single PERSON entity in the code. Check this for further details on how to serialize/deserialize. http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm

Comment: Yes I'm already familiar with serializing/deserializing XML. But I'm just wondering if we could query an XML column in a table directly through an SQL query (e.g. `SELECT * FROM Person Where...`) and not necessarily a C# program.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck using SQL Server for this task, you can leverage its XML Support. Notably, you can use XPath.

[Using XPath Queries in SQLXML 4.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171802(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score -2):

No matter how your data is organized conceptually, its the DBSM's job to make it fast, so usually, you shouldn't have to worry about whether your query is fast.

The first and most obvious, but also the least recommended way is using [alter table](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) which will allow you to modify the table later on.
The more recommended route is decomposing your table into many tables and relating them with primary keys.

So your person might have as a primary key social security, and attributes name, last name, street address, street name, postal code

Then you would decompose the table into (in pseudocode)

Table Person: social

Table Address: social, street_address, street_name, postal_code

Table Info: social, first_name, last_name

Then you can join them with

```
Select Person.social_security, first_name, last_name [...etc...] from Person, Address, Info where Person.social = Address.social and Person.social = Info.social
```

Then you can keep adding more tables as needed. There's no problem with having lots of rows in the other tables, and only a few in Person, and this is the recommended way because it lessens the number of empty spaces if a person doesn't have an address but does have a first name and last name, and for many other reasons.

Comment: But here we are again creating a fixed number of columns no matter how much we branch them, right?

Comment: Not really, you could just make more tables dynamically if you need to store more information.

Comment: @Geoffrey it sounds like OP has a schemaless design. This would be better suited to a different platform, but dynamically adding columns is not feasible, as per the original post. This would be best for a document database.